# cmake: target_link_libraries - /usr/bin/ld: cannot find X No such file or directory

Tags: c++, cmake, ld

I'm trying to include this library in my project:
https://github.com/kuafuwang/LspCpp.git

I'm using `FetchContent` which succesfully populates _deps/lspcpp-build, _deps/lspcpp-src, _deps/lspcpp-subbuild:

```
FetchContent_Declare(
    lspcpp
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/kuafuwang/LspCpp.git
)
FetchContent_GetProperties(lspcpp)
if(NOT lspcpp_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(lspcpp)
endif()
```

I define my executable:

```
add_executable(myApp
                foo.cpp
                bar.cpp
                ...
)
```

And try to link it:

```
target_include_directories(myApp lspcpp)
target_link_libraries(myApp lspcpp)
```

This produces this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llspcpp: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I believe you need to add_subdirectory(${lspcpp_SOURCE_DIR} ${lspcpp_BINARY_DIR}) within the if statement after populate

Comment: @DoritoJohnson It worked! Feel free to write an answer, then I will be happy to accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a step for FetchContent, to build the library.

```
FetchContent_Declare(
    lspcpp
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/kuafuwang/LspCpp.git
)
FetchContent_GetProperties(lspcpp)
if(NOT lspcpp_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(lspcpp)
    add_subdirectory(${lspcpp_SOURCE_DIR} ${lspcpp_BINARY_DIR}) # add this line
endif()
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems `FetchContent_MakeAvailable(lspcpp)` automatically calls `add_subdirectory`, so you only need that after `FetchContent_Declare`.